# How to import multiple column values with one condition?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having problems in getting the values. I need to get the values of July 10, 2020 to July 25, 2020 under column TL "June Troy". I have tried to do query with importrange and filter with importrange. But I cannot get it right. Please help.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Here it is: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CQkhI5dZoIUfoKF1aQ8lm1Y8rmOOZapaoYBJw8BJTSE/edit#gid=1690669449)

This is the sheet where I will get the data from

Comment: Can you show what the output you want should look like?  You say "get the values" - what values, everything in column J to Y?

Comment: @kirkg13 Let's say I have a different sheet. I want to use importrange and transfer the data showing in the image to my new sheet. The condition is TL value is June Troy. The values are the numbers and words like "AWOL, LWOP, RD.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the following query should work for you:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CQkhI5dZoIUfoKF1aQ8lm1Y8rmOOZapaoYBJw8BJTSE/edit?usp=sharing","Attendance!A1:BC99")})),
"select Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col17,Col18,Col19,Col20,Col21,Col22,Col23,Col24,Col25 where Col7 = 'June Troy' ",1)
```

Note that since your test data has June Troy on every row, this ends up selecting every row.

More importantly, your "value" columns have mixed data types, both numeric and string values, and `QUERY` ignores the minority data types and returns blanks for those values.  So I included the `TO_TEXT` function to convert individual cells to text before passing them to the `QUERY`.  And to make the `TO_TEXT` act on every cell in the range, it is wrapped in an `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Let us know if this works for you.

UPDATED: To correct formula.  Sorry about that.

Comment: If you did not have the mixed data types, the following query would work:   ```=QUERY({Attendance!A1:BC99},"select Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col17,Col18,Col19,Col20,Col21,Col22,Col23,Col24,Col25 where Col7 = 'June Troy' ",1)```

Comment: thank you. however, there is an error on the first formula. "Wrong number of arguments to TO_TEXT. Expected 1 arguments, but got 3 arguments."

In the actualy spreadsheet, there's other options aside from June Troy. But all I want is to get data from June Troy.

Comment: Sorry, I'd tried to make a quick revision to the formula, and created an error.  It has been updated to add two missing parentheses.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! The first one you provided to me.

Comment: Quick question if I may. Is it possible to connect two importrange? Like in one cell with one formula. I'll use that formula you provided me for col1 to col9. Then the following columns should be Col15toCol42 but from a different link.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to your second question, which should perhaps be a separate from the first part, since it is a different issue.  But yes, you should be able to connect two `IMPORTRANGE` queries.  Consider this formula:

```
={
QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CQkhI5dZoIUfoKF1aQ8lm1Y8rmOOZapaoYBJw8BJTSE/edit?usp=sharing","Attendance!A1:BC99")})),
"select Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15 
  where Col7 = 'June Troy' ",1),
QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CQkhI5dZoIUfoKF1aQ8lm1Y8rmOOZapaoYBJw8BJTSE/edit?usp=sharing","Attendance!A1:BC99")})),
"select Col16,Col17,Col18,Col19,Col20,Col21,Col22,Col23,Col24,Col25 
  where Col7 = 'June Troy' ",1)
}
```

Basically, you would have two very similar queries.  In my example, I point them both at the same sheet, but you can point to a different link, for one of the queries.

They are wrapped in braces, "{...}", to form a new array.  And most importantly, the first query has a comma, ",", after it, to force the result of the second query to be in adjacent columns, on the same rows.  If you separate the two queries with a semi-colon, ";", the result of the second query would be added as rows underneath the first query, not in columns beside it.

HOWEVER, I think this causes an error if the two queries don't both return the same number of rows.  So that will depend on your data.  But since you are getting related columns, I'm assuming they should return the same number of rows.  If not, share the data from your two sample sheets, and what the desired outcome should look like.